# netcat host not found when listening

Tags: windows, netcat, nc

i am trying to connect two hosts using netcat. i have downloaded [netcat for windows](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/), but when i run the command `nc -L -vv -p 4444`, it fails with the error `nc: forward host lookup failed: h_errno 11001: HOST_NOT_FOUND`! I have tried specifying ip 127.0.0.1 and using -l instead of -L, but it didn't make a difference

does anyone kow how to stop this?!

Comment: netcat h_errno 11001 is most likely caused by firewall/av stuff.

Comment: this looks like a simular case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905402/netcat-not-able-to-run-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

You should either run `nc` or `nc64` from the terminal (cmd.exe) with your arguments:
`nc -L -vv -p 4444`
Or (if you prefer to start `nc`/`nc64`) from explorer, you should only input '-L -vv -p 4444' when it asks you for 
`Cmd line:`

So when started as a standalone your terminal window before pressing enter should look like:

`Cmd line: -L -vv -p 4444`

Answer (score -1):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) :

> WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND
>   11001
>   Host not found.
>   No such host is known. The name is not an official host name or alias, or it cannot be found in the database(s) being queried. This error may also be returned for protocol and service queries, and means that the specified name could not be found in the relevant database.

The failure could also be as a result of incorrect proxy configuration. Check proxy connections in Network and Adapter Settings.